# How to parse or actually get push message in Android using GCM

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I'm implementing a GCM client using the example provided by Google (http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html) but when I send the test message then I don't know how to receieve it

Here is the code I use to send the message:

```
String msg = "";                        
gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(BaseHeaderActivity.this);

try {
    Bundle data = new Bundle();
    data.putString("my_message", "Test message");
    data.putString("my_action", "com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.ECHO_NOW");
    String id = Integer.toString(msgId.incrementAndGet());
    gcm.send(ListCategoriesActivity.SENDER_ID + "@gcm.googleapis.com", id, data);
    msg = "Sent message";
} 
catch (IOException ex) {
    msg = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();
}

return msg;
```

The message seems to be sent ok, then the method void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) from GcmIntentService gets executed seconds after I send the message, but the problem is that inside the extras in the intent there are no keys like the ones I put in the method that sends the message:

```
data.putString("my_message", "Test message");
data.putString("my_action", "com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.ECHO_NOW");
```

Here is my GcmIntentService class:

```
public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService {

private final String TAG = "GcmIntentService";

public GcmIntentService() {
        super("GcmIntentService");
    }

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

    Set<String> keys = extras.keySet();
    Log.i(TAG, "Received: " + extras.getString("my_message"));

}

...
}
```

The log is "Received: null", and the keys present in the extras are: 
[message_type, google.message_id, event, android.support.content.wakelockid]

Any ideas??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Did you get answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to send an upstream message (device to cloud) from your device to your server. It will only work if you have a server that establishes a XMPP connection with Google's GCM CCS server. Even if it does work, the message will reach your server, not your device.

Your intent service will get your message only if your server sends it to your device.